# MySQL - writing joins to get data from many-layers linked tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble writing the query for this specific task. Here are the simplified tables:

```
`job`: job_id, school_id
`school`: school_id, country_id
`country`: country_id, region_id
`region`: region_id, region
```

Now, I'm querying the `job` table to get the jobs listing, but I also need to show each job's region (i.e. Europe, Asia, etc.)

How do I do so giving these linked tables?

Comment: please double check those table structures please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what you provide it looks like this:

```
select
*
from `job` j
inner join `school` s on j.school_id = s.school_id
inner join `country`c on s.country_id = c.country_id
inner join `region` r on c.region_id = r.region_id
```

But I think the school table should hold region, or, country and region.